# Dapper needs a parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, orm, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I have a class:

```
public class NListingsData : ListingData, IListingData
    {
        private readonly IMetaDictionaryRepository _metaDictionary;

        //Constructor.
        public NListingsData(IMetaDictionaryRepository metaDictionary)
        {
            _metaDictionary = metaDictionary;
        }

        //Overridden function from abstract base class
        public override List<Images> Photos
        {
            get
            {
                var urlFormat = _metaDictionary.GetDictionary(CommonConstants.ImagesUrlFormat, this.Key);
                var imgs = new List<Images>();

                for (var i = 0; i < PhotosCount; i++)
                {
                    imgs.Add(new Images
                    {
                        Url = string.Format(urlFormat, this.MNumber, i)

                    });
                }
                return imgs;
            }
            set { }
        }
    }
```

The metaDictionary is injected by Autofac.

I am executing a query with Dapper and I try to materialize NListingsData. This is what I am using:

```
string sqlQuery = GetQuery(predicates); //Select count(*) from LView; select * from lView;
//Use multiple queries
            using (var multi = _db.QueryMultipleAsync(sqlQuery,
              new
              {
                  //The parameter names below have to be same as column names and same as the fields names in the function: GetListingsSqlFilterCriteria()
                  @BedroomsTotal = predicates.GetBedrooms(),
                  @BathroomsTotalInteger = predicates.GetBathrooms()
              }).Result)
            {
                //Get count of results that match the query
                totalResultsCount = multi.ReadAsync<int>().Result.Single();
                //Retrieve only the pagesize number of results

                    var dblistings = multi.ReadAsync<NListingsData>().Result; // Error is here
            }
            return dblistings;
```

I get the error

```
A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature (System.Guid ListingId, System.String MLSNumber, System.Int32 BedroomsTotal, System.Double BathroomsTotalInteger) is required for CTP.ApiModels.NListingsData materialization
```

Does my class that I use to materialize with dapper must always be parameterless?

Now, I could create a simple DataModel then map to my ViewModel. But is that the only way to do it?

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit.  No, you don't *need* a parameterless constructor.  You need either a parameterless constructor or one matching the given signature.

Comment: My class actually has about 40 public properties and may grow. To have a constructor with 40 fields?? I wouldn't have posted otherwise.

Comment: Dapper is designed to map database query results to simple POCO's, not full-featured domain models with dependencies. You could create a DTO for Dapper and use that to populate the `NListingsData` model.

Answer (score 3):

Just add an additional private, parameterless, constructor. This will get picked by Dapper.

Answer (score 2):

In F#, add a

```
[<CliMutable>]
```

attribute to your DTO.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add value as the question is about C#, not about F#